# Where does the quote in 1 Corinthians 2:9 come from?

Tags: 1-corinthians, septuagint, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

I have searched with my bible app and I don't seem to find it.

> 1 Corinthians 2:9 NIV
>
> 9 However, as it is written: “What no eye has seen, what no ear has
>   heard, and what no human mind has conceived” b — the things God has
>   prepared for those who love him

Answer (score 2):

The quotation, like a large percentage of OT citations is from the LXX (Greek) rather from the Hebrew. This particular quote is from here:

> LXX and Brenton: Isaiah 64:
>
> 3 ἀπὸ τοῦ αἰῶνος οὐκ ἠκούσαμεν οὐδὲ οἱ ὀφθαλμοὶ ἡμῶν εἶδον θεὸν πλὴν
>   σοῦ καὶ τὰ ἔργα σου ἃ ποιήσεις τοῖς ὑπομένουσιν ἔλεον
>
> 4 From of old we have not heard, neither have our eyes seen a God
>   beside thee, and thy works which thou wilt perform to them that wait
>   for mercy.

This link here shows the LXX source for many NT quotes:

https://biblehub.com/library/swete/an_introduction_to_the_old_testament_in_greek_additional_notes/chapter_ii_quotations_from_the.htm

The role of the LXX in the formation of the NT is somewhat non-intuitive and it is sort of "rite of passage" for someone to discover the non-tidy nature of this aspect of the scriptures.